# Corner Swappings on Rubiks Cube

Tags: recreational-mathematics, rubiks-cube

My brother likes to solve Rubik's cubes. Occasionally I flip a corner or two as an added challenge, and he eventually is able to see where the illegal corner is. The other day, I turned all eight corners and the cube was solvable without any corner turns.

I know that the Rubik's cube is a group and that a corner turn takes the cube out of the group, meaning that we cannot transform the cube back into its fully solved position.

My question is: how many corners need to be turned exactly once for the cube to be a part of the original group that consists of all legal positions? Can I turn just two, or maybe four corners and create a legal position?

Additionally, any good papers or authors to read to learn about the mathematics of the Rubik's Cube?

Comment: You may also be interested in [a mathematical approach to the Rubik's cube and other permutation puzzles](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096592/21820).

Comment: Here is [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34845883/1509264) on representing a cube in a compact format on a computer. If you want details of fast computer algorithms then [Kociemba's Two-Phase algorithm](http://kociemba.org/math/imptwophase.htm). If you want to know about [Gods Number](http://www.cube20.org/) (the minimum number of moves required to solve any cube).

Comment: You could say that a corner turn takes the cube out of the _subgroup_ of all possible cube positions, and into a different subgroup of positions accessible by legal moves only.

Comment: Since a group is defined to only have one operation, I don't think all cube permutations with corner turns can be called a group, implying that the set of "legal positions" is not a subgroup.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you mentioned, turning just one corner (say, clockwise) results in a position that's not in the Rubik's Cube Group, but turning one clockwise and one counterclockwise is!

If we count a clockwise turn as +1 and a counterclockwise turn as -1, then it turns out that as long as our turns add up to 0 mod 3, then that's a legal permutation.  (So turning all eight clockwise is not legal, perhaps you turned one counterclockwise?)

My go-to reference for the Rubik's Cube Group is the book *[Adventures in Group Theory](http://a.co/gQK9msf)* by David Joyner.

Comment: I believe that i may have turned four clockwise and the other four counterclockwise which explains the solvability. Thank you for the explanation and reference

Answer (score 6):

If you turn all the corners one step *the same way* (that is, for example, all clockwise), the resulting configuration is solvable if and only if the number of corners you turned is a **multiple of three**.

So turning all eight corners one step clockwise each will not produce a solvable configuration.

More generally, the cube will remain solvable iff the *difference* between how many corners you turned clockwise and how many corners you turned counterclockwise is a multiple of three.

For example, turning equally many corners clockwise as counterclockwise will produce a solvable configuration, because $0$ is a multiple of $3$ (namely, it is  $0\times 3$).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you turn them. A 1/3 turn clockwise (when looking into the corner from the outside) is called a "quark" and similarly a counter-clockwise rotation is called an "antiquark". In analogy to "real" quarks/antiquarks, you can combine a quark and an antiquark, or you can combine three quarks (or three antiquarks) and still leave the cube in a solvable state. That's IIRC.

Hofstadter's article in Scientific American (ca. 1980) is one reference and [David Singmaster's booklet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0894900439) on the cube is another.